# How to disable browsing history in Android Firefox (Fennec)?

Tags: firefox-for-android

Unlike in the desktop Firefox, there's no setting in Firefox for Android options to disable saving browsing history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to `about:config`.
- Create a new `boolean` value (`+` icon) called `places.history.enabled` and set to `false`.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3jc6rx/firefox_for_android_is_missing_some_important/cuocgg9)

**note**: the answer only applies to the eventually deprecated Firefox Fennec, not [Fenix](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix) which is currently in the beta phase.

Comment: I wish I could do the same on the stable version on Firefox on Android.